# Implement a new feature with loose coupling

Tags: scala, oop, design-patterns

```
trait paymentTasks{
  def calculatePayment()
  def getData()
}

 class paymentcalculator{
    override def calculatePayment() ={
    //Implementation }

    }
    override defGetData() ={
    }
   }
```

How do I call the method to keep the code less dependent and don't want to use new keyword

```
 class MyApp{
   val payment = new paymentcalculator
   //I don't want to instantiate like this wants this to be decoupled

 }
```

Please suggest how do I implement this ,also new Changes in future can be done without changing existing code.Also,suggest if doing this functionally would be more effective

Comment: Why you do not want to call `new`? What does more _"functionally"_ means for you? - In any case, the simples and best way is that your class receives as a constructor argument an instance of the **PaymenTask** interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want compile-time selection then just put the code into an `object`

```
trait PaymentTasks {
  def calculatePayment()
  def getData()
}

object PaymentCalculator extends PaymentTasks {
  def calculatePayment() = ???
  def getData() = ???
}

class MyApp {
  val payment = PaymentCalculator.calculatePayment()
}
```

If you want run-time selection than the best way is to use [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) and create the payment object at the top level and pass it down to the code that requires it.

```
object SimplePaymentCalculator extends PaymentTasks

object ComplexPaymentCalculator extends PaymentTasks

class MyApp {
  def myImplementation(tasks: PaymentTasks) = {
    val payment = tasks.calculatePayment()
  }

  val payment =
    if (???) {
      SimplePaymentCalculator
    } else {
      ComplexPaymentCalculator
    }

  myImplementation(payment)
}
```

Comment: Object for singleton access right? or any other significance.

Comment: They can be a class too, esp. if they need to have something else injected, like config.